# Why LLMs are poor when recognizing weekdays for specific dates?

Tags: llm, llama-2, text-generation

I asked the LLaMA V2 LLM using this site: https://llama2.ai/ - for the respective weekdays for February 29 for leap years since 2000.

Here is the response:

> I'm happy to help! Here are the respective weekdays for February 29, for leap years since 2000:
>
> - 2000: Monday
> - 2004: Wednesday
> - 2008: Tuesday
> - 2012: Thursday
> - 2016: Saturday
> - 2020: Tuesday
>
> I hope that helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

All of these weekdays provided are incorrect, but with some catches: February 29, 2000 was a Monday in the Julian calendar (now obsolete), but not in the Gregorian (currently used). (In the Gregorian calendar that day was a Tuesday).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LLMs can't do math.  LLMs work by recognizing patterns in the training data, and using those patterns to produce the most probable continuation of the input.  In order to correctly determine what day of the week a given February 29 is, an LLM needs to see it often enough in the training data to form a consistent response.

It's possible to train an LLM to recognize something as a day-of-week query and forward it to a calendar service, but I don't know if any of the current ones do so.

(In my testing, I found that Gemini Pro is quite insistent that there haven't been any leap years since 2000, while Vicuna is convinced that February 29 always falls on a Tuesday.)